# How to apply a list of functions using tidyverse and get back a column for each function applied

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to apply multiple functions to each column in a data set and get back a column for each function that was computed and the rows would then correspond to which column it was computed on. So in the code below, there are 3 IDs. I then compute three functions on each so the final data frame would have 3 rows and 3 columns. The rows now correspond to which Id the function was computed on and the column corresponds to what was computed. I am open to other solutions but would prefer a tidyverse solution since I need it to be generalizable to a lot of functions and still be fast.

The expected output is in end.data

```
data <- data.frame(id1 = 1:10,id2 = 1:10,id3 = 1:10)
data

end.data <- data.frame(innprod = c(385,385,385),identity = c(55,55,55) , range = c(9,9,9))
end.data
```

I tried combining across and summarise which does the calculations but it returns each in their own column.

```
data <- data.frame(id1 = 1:10,id2 = 1:10,id3 = 1:10)
map.fun <- list(
  innprod = ~ t(.x)%*%.x, 
  identity = ~ sum(.x),
  range = ~ max(.x) - min(.x)
)
feat_m <-      data %>%  summarise(across(where(is.numeric),map.fun))
feat_m
```

Comment: The expected out is in end.data. Will edit question to make that clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could reshape to 'long' format and then apply as a function

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
map.fun <- function(.x) list(
  innprod =  as.numeric(t(.x)%*%.x), 
 identity =  sum(.x),
 range =  max(.x) - min(.x)
)

data %>% 
       select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
       pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
       group_by(name) %>% 
       summarise(value = list(map.fun(value)), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
       unnest_wider(c(value))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  name  innprod identity range
#  <chr>   <dbl>    <int> <int>
#1 id1       385       55     9
#2 id2       385       55     9
#3 id3       385       55     9
```

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't thought of changing out of the current format. Clever! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Your function for `map.fun` returns a matrix for `inprod`, we first need to convert it into vector like rest of the elements.

```
map.fun <- list(
  innprod = ~ c(t(.x)%*%.x), 
  identity = ~ sum(.x),
  range = ~ max(.x) - min(.x)
)
```

Once you do that you can use `summarise` + `across` to apply the function to each numeric column. If you want each value into separate column you can then use `pivot_longer` on summarised data with `names_sep` argument.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%  
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric),map.fun)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric), 
               names_to = c('id', '.value'), 
               names_sep = '_') 

#   id    innprod identity range
#  <chr>   <dbl>    <int> <int>
#1 id1       385       55     9
#2 id2       385       55     9
#3 id3       385       55     9
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R alternative, which is essentially a hidden double loop. Still generalisable to many functions as requested:

```
funs <-  c(
  innprod  = function(x) c(t(x) %*% x),
  identity = sum,
  range    = function(x) diff(range(x))
)
sapply(funs, function(f) sapply(data, function(d) f(d)) )

#    innprod identity range
#id1     385       55     9
#id2     385       55     9
#id3     385       55     9
```